# Allowing attach from Google Drive pop-up on Fluid app pointing at Asana

Tags: google, fluid.app

I have setup a Fluid App for Asana, and I have whitelisted the various URLs required for logging in.  However, I am unable to attach things using Google Drive because it requires viewing a pop-up.  I have checked the URL for this pop-up and whitelisted it, but it is still not displayed in Fluid.  Do you know how to make it so that I can attach things from Google Drive using Fluid?